# Resumable.js - retrive success server response

Tags: javascript, ajax, resumablejs

How do I get the response data from the last chunk uploaded? I cant find it anywhere, the only thing that I found was that you can only access the message on error

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! If you want to retrive the data from the file uploading you need this:

```
    r.on('fileSuccess', function(file, event) {
        console.log(event);
    });
```